# Get random records from rails 5 but keep one record(based on some value ) on top

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a Question table. It has a dummy question in it , i want to get the question in random but that dummmy question should always be on top in the returned ActiveRecord collection. I can get the records in random buy using `Random()` function which is working fine  but that dummy question has also random position which i dont want, i want it to be on first position. Any solution would be helpful.

Question table columns: `id, statement, answer`
The dummy question has blank statement.

Query i am using

```
Question.all.order("Random()")
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please share table structure of Question table. And your query that you are using to select random records. Please do not add it in comment, add it in your question itself by editing the question.

Comment: you are not using activerecord?

Comment: yes i am using it

Comment: What specifically does "blank" mean with respect to the `statement` column? NULL? An empty string? Something else?

Comment: If id is primary key then you can do something like- `order by id=dummy_que_id desc` in your query.

Comment: @muistooshort empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option:

```
select_clause = "(CASE WHEN (statement = '') THEN 0 ELSE Random() END) as dummy, questions.*"
Question
  .select(select_clause)
  .order('dummy')
```

Second option:

```
select_clause = "(statement <> '') as dummy, questions.*"
Question
  .select(select_clause)
  .order('dummy, Random()')
```

**Edit**: `statement` shouldn't contain NULL in both options

Comment: thanx... exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @TasawarHussain You have to note: `random()` and `ORDER BY random()` are not fast enough on big tables.

Comment: @pravel it can also be done Question.order('statement <> '', Random()')

Comment: @TasawarHussain Yes, but when you modified `select` you have an option to use `question_instance.dummy` in the code later.